# Put ASP.NET MVC application in subdirectory of main MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have my main website's application on my server at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, which I can view at `http://www.mysite.com`

I've created another separate MVC web application, named `Subdir`. I'd like to set it up so that if I visit `http://www.mysite.com/Subdir`, it will run my `Subdir` app.

What do I need to do for that? I obviously can't just drop the app in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.webui\whatever`. Do I need to put the application in a certain directory? Do I need to configure anything in IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can drop the application in a subfolder of your original applicaiton, but the important thing is how you set up IIS for this new application. I suggest using sibling/parallel folders as a best practice.

1. Deploy your applications in a sibling folder:

   `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\` is your main app

   `c:\inetpub\mynewapp\` for your secondary application.
2. In IIS, expand your existing website and add a new Application, pointing the root folder to `c:\inetpub\mynewapp\`

**Result:**

`http://mysite` = `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\`

`http://mysite/mynewapp/` = `c:\inetpub\mynewapp`

You're all good, and this is a pretty accepted "best practice" as you can tighten down NTFS and App Pool Identities easier now. Look up information on these topics and you'll be a step ahead of the game with your sites deployed this way.

Answer (score 5):

> I obviously can't just drop the app in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.webui\whatever`

Incorrect.
You need to do exactly that.

Just mark that directory as an Application in IIS manager and you're good to go.

Comment: Haha, well then clearly I have no idea what I'm talking about.