# Linking from HTML page to MVC view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I have a legacy site that uses `shtml` pages.  I have a project to add dynamic functionality to this site -- an MVC app where the user uploads files and the controller generates an email.

For legacy reasons, I am not able to rewrite the site.  I also do not have web admin access to the site; I can only work with files in my area.  The path I have to work with is `//host/foo/bar/baz`.

According to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247131/navigate-from-html-page-to-mvc-view), I ought to be able to make a link in the originating static page within the directory **baz** as `<a href="Controller/Action">link text</a>`.  I tried that, and after fixing up issues with the app's `web.config` file, I got a 404 error.  This does make sense now that I think about it, as there is no directory in `baz` called `Controller` -- only `bin`, `Views`, and the like.  The physical path not found is `foo/bar/baz/Controller/Action`.

There are plenty of articles and Stack Overflow questions about adding a static page to an MVC app, but I have found nothing discussing the other direction.

How do I link from the static HTML page to the MVC action?

(I may have follow-on questions as I try to get the app to run.)

*Edited to add*:
I tried moving the MVC app code to the top level of the web site (in my development environment).  When I used the link this time, I encountered a configuration error in my IoC file, with mismatched versions of Entity Framework.  This approach might be promising, and it also might encounter permissions issues in the operational environment.

Also, I do not have write permissions to the root level of the web server's documents area, only my subdirectory area.

Comment: You need to enter the URL to the MVC App. If is "inside" your site in a virtual directory, your URL will be relative to your site. If it is hosped somewhere else, it should be an absolute URL. In an MVC site, you don't rely in folders, there are Routes defined, so it is OK to use the format "Host/YourMVCSite/Controller/Action"

Comment: It's hosted in my site, but I can't set up virtual directories.  That's a pity, as I think that's a good way to go.  Now the bad part:  I do not have write permissions to the server root directory.  So I may have to host the app somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/Controller/Action">link text</a>
```

Try with "/" before controller

Comment: That works in development, subject to reconciling the package versions.  If I had full control over the web server, I'd probably accept your answer as correct.  But I can't deploy my app to the root level of the server.  So at least I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Follow-on question to The World:  Is there a way to deploy my app in a subdirectory on the site, somewhere that I do have write access?

Comment: Follow-up to my follow-up: There is a way: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584288/put-asp-net-mvc-application-in-subdirectory-of-main-mvc-application)